# Typescript: Get property field names of type

Tags: typescript

I need to get all properties of type `number` of a type:

```
export interface ApplicationQuote {
    readonly chronoUnit: ApplicationQuote.ChronoUnitEnum;
    readonly downloadedDocs: number;
    readonly downloadedKb: number;
    readonly uploadedKb: number;
    readonly uploadedRefs: number;
}
export namespace ApplicationQuote {
    export type ChronoUnitEnum = 'HOUR' | 'DAY' | 'MONTH' | 'YEAR';
    export const ChronoUnitEnum = {
        HOUR: 'HOUR' as ChronoUnitEnum,
        DAY: 'DAY' as ChronoUnitEnum,
        MONTH: 'MONTH' as ChronoUnitEnum,
        YEAR: 'YEAR' as ChronoUnitEnum
    };
}
```

I need to get an `Array<string>` like `["downloadedDocs", "downloadedKb", "uploadedKb", "uploadedRefs"]`.

I've tried this code:

```
let names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ApplicationQuote);
let keys = Object.keys(ApplicationQuote);
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript looping through class type properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944763/typescript-looping-through-class-type-properties)

Comment: You can not access interface through Object.keys, Typescript interfaces are not transpiled into javascript
But you can get a union type of interface property names.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm going to rename your `ApplicationQuote` interface to `IApplicationQuote`, to distinguish it from the `ApplicationQuote` namespace.  One major issue you will immediately find is that you can't do anything like `Object.keys(IApplicationQuote)`:

```
Object.keys(IApplicationQuote); // error!
// 'IApplicationQuote' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

An interface is a part of TypeScript's type system, which is completely [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) from the emitted JavaScript.  Interfaces only exist at design time, while you're writing the program, and can be checked at compile time, when the JavaScript is emitted... but they are gone by runtime.  So there is nothing named `IApplicationQuote` at runtime to process.

You will therefore need to write something like:

```
const numericProps = [
  "downloadedDocs",
  "downloadedKb",
  "uploadedKb",
  "uploadedRefs"
] as const;
```

(The `as const` is a [`const` assertion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions) which allows the compiler to treat `numericProps` as a tuple of string literals instead of as just a `string[]`).

---

There are a few ways to proceed from here, then.  One is to keep your interface and use the compiler to help ensure that your `numericProps` value has all and only the right members.  First we can define `KeysMatching<T, V>`, which evaluates to a union of keys in `T` which are assignable to the type `V`:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = NonNullable<
  { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T]
>;
```

And use it like this:

```
type NumericProps = KeysMatching<IApplicationQuote, number>;
// type NumericProps = "downloadedDocs" | "downloadedKb" | "uploadedKb" | "uploadedRefs"
```

Armed with the `NumericProps` type, we can write this:

```
type MutuallyAssignable<T extends U, U extends V, V = T> = true;

type NumericPropsOkay = MutuallyAssignable<
  typeof numericProps[number],
  NumericProps
>; // okay
```

You can use `MutuallyAssignable<T, U>` to ensure that the types you pass in for `T` and `U` are equivalent; if not, you will get an error (so `MutuallyAssignable<string, string | "a">` is fine, but `MutuallyAssignable<number, number | "a">` is not).  Since `NumericPropsOkay` does not yield an error, you know you haven't made a mistake with `numericProps`.

Consider what happens if you change `numericProps` like this:

```
const numericProps = [
  "downloadedDocs",
  "downloadedKb",
  "uploadedkb", // <-- note the typo
  "uploadedRefs"
] as const;
```

Then this will happen:

```
type NumericPropsOkay = MutuallyAssignable<
  typeof numericProps[number], // error!
  NumericProps
>;
// Type '"uploadedkb"' is not assignable to type 
// '"downloadedDocs" | "downloadedKb" | "uploadedKb" | "uploadedRefs"'.
```

So you can use this to make sure your manually-written array and your interface definition don't diverge in the future.

---

The other way to proceed is to define your interface in terms of the `numericProps` value.  That is, do the reverse of what you asked for... JavaScript doesn't know anything about TypeScript, but TypeScript does know about JavaScript.  So you can take this:

```
const numericProps = [
  "downloadedDocs",
  "downloadedKb",
  "uploadedKb",
  "uploadedRefs"
] as const;
```

And use it to define this interface:

```
export interface IApplicationQuote
  extends Readonly<Record<typeof numericProps[number], number>> {
  readonly chronoUnit: ApplicationQuote.ChronoUnitEnum;
}
```

Here we have defined `IApplicationQuote` to extend `Readonly<Record<typeof numericProps[number], number>>`, which is essentially the same as `{readonly downloadedDocs: number, readonly downloadedKb: number, ...}`.  We only had to add the one non-numeric property in there.  And you can make sure it works:

```
const appQuote: IApplicationQuote = {
  chronoUnit: "DAY",
  downloadedDocs: 1,
  downloadedKb: 2,
  uploadedKb: 3,
  uploadedRefs: 4
}; // okay
```

And you can verify that `IApplicationQuote` is still the type you're looking for:

```
const badAppQuote: IApplicationQuote = {
  chronoUnit: "DAY",
  downloadedDocs: 1,
  downloadedKb: 2,
  uploadedkb: 3, // error!
  uploadedRefs: 4
}; 
// 'uploadedkb' does not exist in type 'IApplicationQuote'. 
// Did you mean to write 'uploadedKb'?
```

Looks good.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false#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-3h+PJ5yOOvhyF2SCzpAWDwAACjoMB0o8Pa2v2tCDsAJZDpG6xWFstgQDm4wYMBIa+mBEEYAIsFUPBRJPKE4TNNEcQJPCdH5AxRSlKxjSFC0JQpNx-R8UMIxPB2SCYsA2JjF4FEwXBCGbl0bEFIxsTxFATxspkKkcXxXHafITw8WpBnKSZgzDJpchXnyknYiBnYnMgYL5hIDbqJwUBQJgJagEuK7Qtet73kgeg5nowUQHeD5jkS0KTo8tDoE21RkbJUFUfBbyWiA+CPK5tDufOuBeT5fmLsuq6ZF2-7JHJWVQBuhHoCehmkORmUKUBvjTKAkCwGwSAAEISJgvDKMSElYvQ9VddRikbsp9G8UxGlact7GrfxG06RZ+kCe1zz7dEInWaQtl0vZtCOdecwFkwLBDVhzoxnhXQUCFdJDD06hDkMmLoMoQ61Uec2UQpzUVBgbUyR06DjpOew1NkiZaBc8omKsUY4a69hakKXj6jMlCHAsA3LMg5jYS6sa7B9pPzGBBMKncjyUp8rE8r8zxSnCPNPOqTyondZPXfyGPaskRLI5kZIDBS8syhLeKs2AR0ckC3JAsrLPMl4GuilCsKSsb-OagKmMEob6pqkiGqypbUteLqxOkOLIA8HTpgvdGuE7DLXTo6rWNPDyR0rWpzGjAAjBHW2mWUSAAExHSd-GmAAzGnQmnVZpgACxyHq3q+lQuW4EQ0xAA)

Comment: Slightly related to this question... I landed here when searching for how to do this in TypeScript... the answer for me turned out to be to use `keyof`, which I hadn't heard of before: `type FormValues = typeof form.values; /* https://mantine.dev/form/use-form/#get-form-values-type */   type FieldName = keyof FormValues;`